# I need a sparepart, but how is it called?

Tags: drive-shaft

[image: This is where the drive shaft is sitting]

The drive shaft jumped (due to a failing wishbone) out of the housing in the motor. I want to order a new part, because it is not included in the new drive shaft. How is it called?

Comment: can you describe it better,is it the flange or the axle part or the connecting rod,it is hard for me to understand exactly what part(s) you want the name of.

Comment: The piece in the photograph is the outer CV joint.

Comment: @SteveMatthews  Surely that is the inner CV joint.  That looks more like a gearbox/differential than a hub.

Comment: @HandyHowie of course.  I must have mistaken the bellhousing for the brake back plate but that big drain key is a dead giveaway.  Yes, Inner CV Joint.

Comment: @trondhansen I need the part with the 6 screws

Comment: @Marvin i guess you have got your answer in the comments,it is the inner CV joint.

Comment: You are best to replace the whole CV axle assembly.

Comment: What make/model/year and position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is the inner CV joint.  Make sure you get a rubber gaiter and grease with the new one.  You will likely need to re-use the bolts.